# Regex which matches part of path

Tags: regex

i'm looking for a regex which matches everything after `example/` until the end of the string or until the first next slash:

1. example/matchingrandomtext12345
2. example/matchingrandomtext12345/
3. example/matchingrandomtext12345/moretext

all 3 examples should match `matchingrandomtext12345` and the regex should not use positive lookbehind.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `example/([^/]+)`. If you are lucky what you need is in first capturing group. It will help if you tag your question with a language or a tool.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which language you are using, but you should use this expression: `example/(.*?)(/|$)` and match the group 1, check the following snippet in Java, it returns exactly what you want...

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class Regex3 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("example/(.*?)(/|$)");

        List<String> entries = Arrays.asList(
            "example/matchingrandomtext12345", 
            "example/matchingrandomtext12345/", 
            "example/matchingrandomtext12345/moretext"
        );

        for (String entry : entries) {
            Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(entry);
            matcher.find();
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        }
    }
}
```

It returns the output:

```
matchingrandomtext12345
matchingrandomtext12345
matchingrandomtext12345
```

Hope I have helped!